# How can I know whether a rotator cuff tear is caused by overuse or subacromial impingement?

Tags: tendinopathy, rotator-cuff

Is an individual has a rotator cuff tear, how can I  whether it was caused by overuse or subacromial impingement?

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.